# How to solve token issue in Discord.py?

Tags: discord

I tried to write the code for the discord bot (Python based) but this leads to the problem shown below. I have a problem on line 10 (where the token is specified). The entered token is correct, but this problem occurs at startup (shown even below). Should I add more bot information (ID, NAMEBOT, etc.) to this code, or create another code in this project and put the above information in there? Or maybe I should look at the error code (I couldn't find them).
If you know a solution, then write, thanks in advance to everyone ...

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Start')

bot.run('MTA1OTg1NjM4MDY5OTM0NDkzOQ.GQPBhe._E1ZDWBr1LhWwdCBrir3ivzEzliBt9d1VnCxGY')
```

(picture problem)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem with you code is the intents that you have set with your bot. This is because `Intents.all()` requires privelliges. To get the code to work you should change the level of intents you want. Such as:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.default())
```

Note: You should never share your token. When you post questions about your bot please replace it with `TOKEN` or something similar to prevent people from accessing your bot.